# How to keep certain amount of decimal places (instead of effective numbers) in C++?

Tags: c++, io

In algorithm competitions, there are sometimes problems that require the solution to keep certain amount of decimal places, for example (when keeping 2 decimal places) the output for `3` is `3.00` and the output for `3.1415926` is `3.14`.

However, `std::setprecision` cannot meet the requirement, as it controls the amount of **effective numbers** instead of **decimal places**. For example, the following code

```cpp
std::cout << set::precision(5) << 123.456;
```

actually produces the output

```
123.46
```

instead of the expected

```
123.45600
```

And what is really required is the exactly same output as the following `printf` does:

```cpp
printf("%.5lf", 123.456);
```

So how can I keep certain amount of decimal places, instead of effective numbers, in C++? In my view, `printf` may not be a good idea, because personally I think `printf` exists in C++ only for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Try https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt. I use it whenever I need console output

Comment: not really convinced it is answered by the answer pointed on the duplicate... at least would need to show an example